# jQuery on image error - show different image if original does not exist (Bootstrap File Input)

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, asp-classic

I am using ([Bootstrap File Input](https://plugins.krajee.com/file-input)) component for file upload, which is working as a charm.. I have defined the initialPreviewConfig to show the existing image on server, but sometimes theres no file for the given user, so I need to display another image, which normally in HTML I would do with the below onerror, but this is not working, properbly because I am not wise enough to find the correct numbers or combination of " & ' (Tried alot of them!) .. but maeby because that does not work in the JS .. Can anyone help me to find a solution?

**The onerror I have tried in the JS below:**

```
onerror="this.src='https://example.com/img/missing.jpg'"
```

**My source:**

```js
$("#input-fas").fileinput({
    theme: "fas",
    uploadUrl: "/file-upload-batch/2",
    allowedFileExtensions: ['jpg'],
    overwriteInitial: false,
    maxFileSize:2000,
    maxFilesNum: 1,
    language: "da",
    initialPreview: [
    "<img src='/profile_pictures/web/<%=Request.QueryString("initials")%>.jpg' class='file-preview-image' alt='Nuværende' title='Nuværende' onerror='this.src=''https://example.com/img/missing.jpg'' style='width: 75%'>",  
],
// initial preview configuration
initialPreviewConfig: [
    {
        caption: 'Nuværende (<%=Request.QueryString("initials")%>.jpg)', 
        width: '120px', 
        frameAttr: {
            title: 'Nuværende',
        },
    }
],
    slugCallback: function (filename) {
        return filename.replace('(', '_').replace(']', '_');
    },
});
```

```html
<div style="width: 550px;">
    <input id="input-fas" name="input-fas[]" type="file" multiple>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should check if the file exists first, if not use the default path. I'm out of my wheelhouse here with JSP(? I'm guessing, you didn't tag your backend language) but I found [this](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1199863) and attempted to adapt it to your needs. It's logically sound but I have no idea if it works and no way to test it.

```
ServletContext app = getServletContext();
String path1 = app.getRealPath("/profile_pictures/web/<%=Request.QueryString("initials")%>.jpg");
File theImage1 = new File(path1);

String imageURL1 = "https://example.com/img/missing.jpg";

if(theImage1.exists())
{
    imageURL1 = "/profile_pictures/web/<%=Request.QueryString("initials")%>.jpg";
}

...

initialPreview: [
    "<img src='<%=imageURL1%>' class='file-preview-image' alt='Nuværende' title='Nuværende' style='width: 75%'>",  
],
```

Comment: THANK YOU @Arleigh Hix .. Although it is ASP (Active Server Pages) and not JSP that Helped me ALOT!! .. your code example offcause did not work since it is JSP, but that led me to the right way .. I will post answer with my code, but you deserve the points ;-)

Comment: Ok good deal. I've never worked with either, you should tag your question ASP.

Comment: Yes deffinetly :-D .. I have just added ASP Classic to it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

After the postet example by @Arleigh Hix, although that script was JSP and not ASP, his logic got me thinking .. so I ended up using the File System Object and the resulting working code you see below:

```
Dim ProfileImage, path, fso

path = "img/profile_pictures/web/" & Request.Querystring("initials") & ".jpg"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If fso.FileExists(Server.MapPath(path)) Then
   ProfileImage = path
Else
   ProfileImage = "img/profile_pictures/web/missing.jpg"
End If

Set fso = Nothing
```

Comment: Don’t you need `Server.MapPath()` they?

Comment: @user692942 .. You are correct, I have just updated the last code with the correct one - Thank you.